# What does the WS mean in WCF?

Tags: wcf

In wcf , What does the `WS - *` mean in WCF?

Is there any reason for it to be grouped ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are Web Service (WS) standards. [This blog post](http://blogs.jinishans.com/2007/03/what-ws-standards-supported-by-wcf.html) explain the ones that are implemented by WCF. They are grouped because together they form the WS-* architecture.

Comment: read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind